# Variance of coin tosses conditioned on their sum

Tags: probability, variance, references, conditional-probability

**Problem setting**

Let $X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n$ be tosses of coins (heads = 1, tails = 0) with mean $\mu_1, \mu_2, \cdots,\mu_n$. Let $S(\vec{X})=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ and denote variance of the random variable $X_i$ by $\operatorname{Var}(X_i)$.

**Question**

1. Can we upperbound $  \sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{Var}(X_i )- \sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E} \Big[\operatorname{Var}\big(X_i \;\big|\; S(\vec{X}) \big)\Big]$?  This measures of how much one learns about $X_i$'s given their sum.
2. Is the above difference maximized for $\mu_i=1/2$?

**Observation**

When all the $\mu_i$'s are equal, the above difference is upper-bounded by a constant lesser than 1/4.

Comment: I suspect the above difference is bounded by $\log (n)$ because $S(\vec{X})$ only gives $\log n$ bits of information. However, I am not sure how to make this rigorous

Comment: Relevant topic that could be useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution.

Comment: Relevant paper for question 2 - https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.01570.pdf

Comment: Also I think you're interested in a lower and not an upper bound. The only upper bound is a trivial one equal to the leftmost term since if the sum is zero or $n$ all the variances are zero.

Comment: @dsaxton : I have added an expectation on the negative term to answer your question.

Comment: In that case if you can work out the distribution of $X_i \mid S_n$ then you don't need any bounds, you'd have the exact answer which is $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \text{Var} [ \text{E} (X_i \mid S_n) ]$.

Comment: @dsaxton: Distribution of $X_i | S_n$ is complicated. Also, I was looking for a bound independent of the $\mu_i$'s.